# Backup another database with BackUpWordPress plugin

Tags: database, backup

Is there any possibilities to add another database which is connected to other wordpress plugin?
My site is using two database: main wordpress db and additional db for plugin data. The Backup includes only the main one. But i want to include the other one too.

Comment: Your question may be better suited for the plugin support forum at WordPress http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/backupwordpress